# Cannot convert generic type parameter

Tags: c#

I need to call a method that accepts an interface as a parameter.  The object I am using as a parameter implements the inteface however I still get a compile error.  What am I doing wrong?

```
public class ViewModel 
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        QueueManager<CFMessage<CFQueueItem>, CFQueueItem> q = new QueueManager<CFMessage<CFQueueItem>, CFQueueItem>();
        DoSomething(q);     // This line does not compile:  Cannot convert from QueueManager<CFQueueItem> to QueueManager<IQueueItem>
    }

    public void DoSomething(QueueManager<IQueueMessage<IQueueItem>, IQueueItem> queueManager)
    {

    }
}

public interface IQueueMessage<T> where T : IQueueItem
{
    int ID { get; set; }
}

public interface IQueueItem
{
    int ID { get; set; }
}

public class CFMessage<CFQueueItem> : IQueueMessage<CFQueueItem> where CFQueueItem : IQueueItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

public class CFQueueItem : IQueueItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

public class QueueManager<T, Q>
    where T : IQueueMessage<Q>
    where Q : IQueueItem
{

}
```

Comment: You should really consider using `var` for variable declarations that complex.

Comment: The object you want to pass implements `QueueManager<CFMessage<CFQueueItem>, CFQueueItem>`, not `QueueManager<IQueueMessage<IQueueItem>, IQueueItem>`.  The first type is no more a subtype of the second than `List<string>` is a subtype of `List<object>`.

Comment: @phoog Sorry for not getting it but I dont understand why you say that.  CFMessage implements IQueueMessage and CFQueueItem implements IQueueItem which is what the method expects.

Comment: @Sam ok, in brief: You cannot pass a `List<string>` to a method expecting `List<object>` because that method could do something like this: `list.Add(1)`, which would fail.  Similarly, `DoSomething` could pass *any* type implementing IQueueManager to its queueManager parameter (if it had a method like `ManageItem(IQueueManager)`; if the queueManager object is actually a QueueManager<CFQueueMessage<CFQueueItem>, CFQueueItem>, but the method passes an XYQueueItem, there would be a run-time error.  The compiler disallows this at compile time, so there's no need for type checks at runtime.

Comment: @Sam more generally, for any types `B`, `D` (where `D` is derived from or implements `B`) and `C<T>`, `C<D>` is not a subtype of `C<B>`, even though `D` *is* a subtype of `B`.  Read Eric Lippert's (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/) comprehensive series on co- and contravariance: http://blogs.msdn.com/search/searchresults.aspx?q=covariance

Comment: @phoog thank you for your patience I clearly have some reading to do.  Here is what throws me:  I can create a method that takes an IQueueItem and pass it a CFQueueItem and it works:                                                                 public void DoSomethingElse(IQueueItem item)
        {
            item.ID = 1;
        }                                                                      in the constructor:  CFQueueItem item = new CFQueueItem();
            DoSomethingElse(item);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17984/discussion-between-phoog-and-sam)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can work around by using concept [*covariance*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx), define interface `IQueueMessage` as *covariant*, using keyword `out`:

```
public interface IQueueMessage<out T> where T : IQueueItem
{
}
```

Then create new covariant interface `IQueueManager` for `QueueManager`:

```
public interface IQueueManager<out T, out Q> where T : IQueueMessage<Q>
                                             where Q : IQueueItem
{
}

public class QueueManager<T, Q> : IQueueManager<T, Q>
    where T : IQueueMessage<Q>
    where Q : IQueueItem
{

}
```

Then you can use this interface for method `DoSomething`:

```
public void DoSomething(IQueueManager<IQueueMessage<IQueueItem>, IQueueItem> queueManager)
{
}
```

Your code will compile successfully:

```
public ViewModel()
{
    var q = new QueueManager<CFMessage<CFQueueItem>, CFQueueItem>();
    DoSomething(q);
}
```

Comment: ... unless the interface isn't safely covariant, in which case it will not compile with the `out` keyword.

Comment: @phoog: yes, you are right, if generic types in here are not result types.

Comment: Thank you very much I would have never figured this out.  I still don't know why it works but it does.

Answer (score 3):

Try making the method generic; this will work even if the interface cannot be made covariant:

```
public void DoSomething<TMessage, TItem>(QueueManager<TMessage, TItem> queueManager) 
    where TMessage : IQueueMessage<TItem>
    where TItem : IQueueItem
{ 
     //...
}
```

Comment: This does seem to be an obvious solution but the QueueManager property on my ViewModel class is actually going to be a dependency property.  I've just simplified this example to illustrate the problem.

Comment: @Sam in that case, I guess you have a few options.  The three I can think of are to use a covariant interface, as Cuong Le suggests, make the ViewModel class generic, or resort to casting.  If the interface permits, covariance would be the way to go.